# how to convert an .mpd file to mkv or any other format supported by video players

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mpd

I tried downloading a video from a website but the file downloaded was a .mpd file and it was mentioned use ffmpeg to download and rip the file and i have no idea how to do it, i searched for it but didn't got anything

Comment: This site is about programming and not video ripping.